# Integral formula logic

Tags: calculus, integration

For example we have to solve such an integral.How do we apply the steps to reduce the integral to a lower degree(speaking of m and n).How exactly do we apply the multiplication formula for Integrals and on which parts of the whole.$$\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(a^2+x^2)^n}$$ and $$\int \frac{x^m\mathrm{d}x}{(a^2+x^2)^n}$$

Comment: Not sure you are asking here, are $a,b$ just constants ? (then you can pull them out of the integral)

Answer (score 0):

With the way you've written this, it appears that $a$ and $b$ are constants. So,

$$\int\frac{dx}{(a^2+b^2)^n}=\frac1{(a^2+b^2)^n}\int dx=\frac x{(a^2+b^2)^n}+C$$
and

$$\int{x^m\,dx\over(a^2+b^2)^n}=\frac1{(a^2+b^2)^n}\int x^m\,dx={x^{m+1}\over(m+1)(a^2+b^2)^n}+C$$

Comment: sorry edited now! a is constant